# How to ask permission for to Access Network State, Access Wifi State and Internet in libGdx

Tags: android-studio, libgdx

I have tried a lot of ways to ask permission to access Network State but whenever I write it in the render or create method the app gets **crashed**. Please help me, to write a code, so that whenever I open the app I should firstly be asked for **Internet permission**.

In AndroidManifest.xml file,

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

In AndroidLauncher.java file,

```
public void checkConnection(){
        ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if(null != activeNetwork){
            if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Wifi Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Data Network Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Please help me out and also tell in which file and method(Example:-Create, Render) should I write the code to get my problem fixed.

Comment: You have to do it on the main thread, not the game thread.

Comment: We need the crash stack trace to help.